# Add a View to a fragment through ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, android-actionbar

I have a NavigationDrawer with an Actionbar and a Fragment. My Fragment has a ScrollView with a RelativeView I am trying to add other Views to this RelativeView. I end up with a NullExceptionPointer in the addView() method which means one of my objects is null, but I cannot figure it out - though it works if I call addView() in the Fragment class. My question is why is it the way it is. Why do I end up with a NPE. I just want to understand what I am doing wrong.

**With further research it turns out that mContainer is null. But I inflate fragment_main then why is it still null?**

my simplified MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

   private ViewGroup mContainer;

@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main);
    mContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_container);
}

@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.action_add_item:


            addItem(); **// NullPointerException**
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

 public void addItem() {    //method responsible for NPE  


    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ingredient, null);

    final ViewGroup newView =(ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_example,mContainer,false);


    mContainer.addView(newView, 0);
}

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {


    private View nicView;




       public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, final ViewGroup mainContainer = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_container);
        final View nicView = View.inflate(getActivity(),R.layout.nicotine, null);
        mainContainer.addView(nicView, 0);

     return rootView;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I edit my post. It's fixed now.

Comment: What line is the nullpointer in `addItem`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi shouldn't your stack trace show were the NPE occurs ?

Is it possible that the layout inflater is null?

They way i normaly set my inflater is by

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```